# Can I use a PNP BJT as a current sinking voltage supply?

Tags: bjt

I am using a counter MC100E016 and I need to connect a 3 V supply at the Vtt terminal that is able to sink current.

Can I use a PNP transistor with 3V supply at its emitter and the collector connected to the ground with some negative bias at the base as a current sink?

The Vtt terminal can then be connected to the emitter of the BJT.

Will it work?

Comment: Do you mean 'shunt regulator'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vtt must be held at 2V below Vcc, so if your main supply is +5V then you need a *negative* 2V regulator connected between Vcc and Vee. A PNP transistor with 2.6V on the Base would work, but there is an easier way - just replace each 50 Ohm termination with the Thevenin equivalent of 82.5 Ohms to Vcc and 124 Ohms to Vee (GND).

Comment: One problem with just using the Thevenin-equivalent termination is that you burn an extra 25 mA of supply current per termination. If you have more than a couple of (P)ECL connections in a system, it's probably worthwhile to add a more-efficient supply for Vtt.

Comment: Hiw do I upload an image because I have to show you a circuit diagram

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/